# Using triplehead2go with ATEM 1 M/E

Tags: mixer

We have a triplehead2go digital edition that we would like to use with a ATEM 1 M/E video mixer.

We tried setting the th2g to 3x 720 50p and the ATEM to 720 50p, but it didn't work.

This was our setup:

```
Computer -> TH2G -> Projector
                 -> ATEM -> Projector
                 -> Projector
```

Connecting the ATEM directly to a computer with the 720 50p works, and the TH2G works also.

Have anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

So you set the resolution of your TH2G to 720p50? In that case you don't get 720p on every output but 1/3 of that vertically. You have to set your th2g to 3840x720 so you get three 720p signals on your outputs.

I also recommend using the Matrox App for setting resolution modes instead of the windows/osx display manager.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. We set the TH2G to 3x 1280x720/50p = 3840. We did this in the Matrox App and confirmed the resolution and refresh rate in OSX display manager.

Comment: Do you have any hardware at hand to check and confirm the HDMI signal that is coming out the triple head?
I can also recommend doing a firmware upgrade if one is available, we often had weird issues with older firmware versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I might be able to check that in a week or so. I think we have the latest firmware. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: With the triple head in general? We use it a lot at my company and hate it a lot because the make tons of problems but is the only feasible solution on the market if you need one big high-res renderer for your software.
Upgrading the firmware is very easy, you just download an updater software from Maxon and feed it with the latest firmware file from their website.